# Hql Querys for sql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Can you give exact hql Query for this Sql query?

```
SELECT * FROM `ims_product`WHERE
    quantity <= reorder_quantity AND
    reorder_quantity IS NOT NULL AND
    NOT(reorder_quantity=0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using.

```
FROM `ims_product` WHERE `quantity` <= `reorder_quantity` AND `reorder_quantity` != 0;
```

Comment: If my query is correct you can accept my answer.@VenunadhM